# Слияние данных из 2-х списков со словарями по одинаковому ключу и его значению

Tags: python, list, dict

Из разных сервисов получаю 2 списка с пользовательскими данными в виде словарей, в обоих списках в словарях есть одинаковый ключ 'user_id', количество записей в списках может не совпадать,
в списке 'current_list' (данные об активных пользователях из ldap) записей о пользователях будет всегда либо меньше либо равное количеству в списке 'users_list':

```
users_list = [
    {'user_id': '24638', 'phone_name': 'p24638', "some_key": "some_value", ...},
    ...,
    {'user_id': '03283', 'phone_name': 'p03283', "some_key": "some_value", ...},
    {'user_id': '01595', 'phone_name': 'p01595', "some_key": "some_value", ...}
]

current_list = [
    {'user_id': '03283', 'display_name': 'Z.Oleg', 'mail': 'Oleg.Z@example.com', ...},
    ...,
    {'user_id': '01595', 'display_name': 'S.Mikhail', 'mail': 'Mikhail.S@example.com', ...}
]
```

Необходимо дополнить данные пользователя в списке 'current_list' данными из первого списка при совпадении значений ключа 'user_id'. Самое простое решение: пройтись 2 циклами по спискам и обновить данные:

```
for i in current_list:
    for j in users_list:
        if i["user_id"] == j["user_id"]:
            i.update(
                {
                    "phone_name": j["phone_name"],
                    "some_key"  : j["some_value"] 
                }
            )
```

но тогда суммарное количество иттераций будет i*j, а списки могут быть большими и каждый содержать по несколько десятков тысяч записей. Какие еще могут быть варианты смерджить данные, желательно без использования сторонних библиотек?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно два списка превратить в два словаря с ключем в виде `user_id`. Потом провести слияние через `dict.update()`. И преобразовать словарь в список по значениям. Будет около `3*N` (спасибо `GrAnd`) операций.

```
users_list = [
    {'user_id': '24638', 'phone_name': 'p24638', "some_key": "some_value", },
    {'user_id': '03283', 'phone_name': 'p03283', "some_key": "some_value", },
    {'user_id': '01595', 'phone_name': 'p01595', "some_key": "some_value", }
]

current_list = [
    {'user_id': '03283', 'display_name': 'Z.Oleg', 'mail': 'Oleg.Z@example.com', },
    {'user_id': '01595', 'display_name': 'S.Mikhail', 'mail': 'Mikhail.S@example.com', }
]

current_dict = {r['user_id']: r for r in current_list}
for k in users_list:
    if current_dict.get(k['user_id']):
        current_dict[k['user_id']].update(k)
    else:  # Если нужно добавить недостающего пользователя
        current_dict[k['user_id']] = k

current_list = list(current_dict.values())
```

В `current_list`:

```
[{'user_id': '03283', 'display_name': 'Z.Oleg', 'mail': 'Oleg.Z@example.com', 'phone_name': 'p03283', 'some_key': 'some_value'}, {'user_id': '01595', 'display_name': 'S.Mikhail', 'mail': 'Mikhail.S@example.com', 'phone_name': 'p01595', 'some_key': 'some_value'}, {'user_id': '24638', 'phone_name': 'p24638', 'some_key': 'some_value'}]
```

Comment: Создание `users_dict` можно выкинуть и сразу итерироваться по `users_list`.

Comment: Спасибо) Не заметил

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, можно еще выкинуть проверку UserID, создать `user_dict`, а циклом пробегать по `current_list` - в этом случае проверка не нужна.